# Extracting a storage_file's path then set it to a EditText and finally read that file using that path placed in EditText

Tags: android, file, uri, filepath

Advance Thanks for your help!
I am searching for this solution for about two days but not solved yet. So, don't mark it as repetitive question.

Here, how I have tried-
  Reading file path and setting to EditText: (it's working well)
I have used followings to read the file using that path-

```
buttond3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            File folders = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + "Information Security"+"/"+"Decrypted Files");
            if (!folders.exists()) {
                folders.mkdirs();
            }
            try {
                String path= String.valueOf(editTextd2.getText());
                String plain = getStringFromFile(path);
                String decrypted = Encryption_Decryption2.decrypt(plain, "000102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F");
                String file_name= String.valueOf(editTextd4.getText());
                File f = new File(folders + "/" + file_name);
                FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(f);
                OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fileOutput);
                outputStreamWriter.write(decrypted);
                outputStreamWriter.flush();
                fileOutput.getFD().sync();
                outputStreamWriter.close();
             }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Here is the getStringFromFile() method-

```
public static String getStringFromFile (String filePath) throws Exception {
    File fl = new File(filePath);
    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(fl);
    String ret = convertStreamToString(fin);
    fin.close();
    return ret;
}
public static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line).append("\n");
    }
    reader.close();
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Just problem in reading the file using the path. Please help!!!

Comment: Where exactly is the issue at? Is the edit text not providing the path? Can you elaborate on the issue?

Comment: Sure, the issue is in reading file using the file path which has been set in the editTexte2  Please see the code for a while!

Comment: Have you checked the file path? Are you sure the file path is where the data is?

Comment: Yes, I am sure because I am opening that file and setting that path in a editTexte2. When I am going to read that same file using that path or String of editText2, it is not reading the file.